# how to get delta content of file

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am using NuGet package named `ReactiveFileSystemWatcher` where `ObservableFileSystemWatcher` is observable wrapper around the `FileSystemWatcher`.

My text file is continuously appending with new content and I would like to grab only delta change.

Below code give notification when there is a change in file content, but I would like what content appending to the file?

```
using RxFileSystemWatcher;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (var watcher = new ObservableFileSystemWatcher(c => { c.Path = @"C:\Test\"; c.IncludeSubdirectories = true; }))
        {
            watcher.Changed.Select(x => $"{x.Name} was {x.ChangeType}").Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
            watcher.Start();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: The file system does not track that, you would need to determine the delta manually by comparing the new data with the old.

Comment: Ok, thanks for info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the files are always only appended to, and no changes ever occur somewhere in the middle, you could solve this by keeping track of the lengths of all files that you are watching. When ever there is a change, you can simply read the file contents from the old length to the new end of the file.

```
Dictionary<string, long> lengthByFilename = new Dictionary<string, long>();
// TODO: recurse through all existing files to get their lengths and put in 
//       the dictionary

watcher.Changed.Select(x => {
    string addedContent;
    using (var file = File.OpenRead(x.Name)) {
        // Seek to the last known end position
        if (lengthByFilename.ContainsKey(x.Name)) {
            file.Seek(lengthByFilename[x.Name], SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(file)) {
            addedContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    // Update dictionary with new length
    lengthByFilename[x.Name] = (new FileInfo(x.Name)).Length;

    return $"{x.Name} has had this added: {addedContent}";
}).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

Obviously, this piece of code is seriously lacking in error handling, but it's a start. You would have to catch IOExceptions and think of how to handle locked files in a proper way. You will probably need to implement a queue of events that you can iterate over to try and re-try reading the new content.

Comment: this would fail to pick up new files that are added after the subscription is created, would it not?

Comment: I don't think it would. If the filename is not known, this code simply does not seek, but rather reads the entire file, and then stores the size of the new file correctly in the dictionary.

Comment: new entries are never be added to the dictionary, in addition wouldn't `lengthByFilename[x.Name] = ...` throw if `x.Name` isn't already present in the dictionary?

Comment: When a new file is created, the watcher reacts and the Select lambda func is invoked. x.Name then contains the name of the added file. The indexer `lengthByFilename[x.Name] = ...` is perfectly fine to do both adds and updates in a Dictionary. I guess you are more into Java than C#?

Comment: Not a java guy, C# is my background actually... was thinking of accessing keys that aren't in the dic rather than adding/updating. That's what I get for looking at JS for too long - over-defensive coding in typed langs!

Comment: @ Anders Tornblad, do I need to loop over file to fill `lengthByFilename` before `watcher.Changed`

Comment: I filled dictionary `lengthByFilename`  before `watcher.Changed`, but after changing content, nothing appears as result

Comment: There is a big possibility that the subscription actually crashes all over the place if you don't handle `IOException`s properly, and then you won't get any output. Try implementing a queue of events and handle that queue, possibly in another thread.